# Unexpected singularities in an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, singularity

I am doing an indefinite integral,

$$f=\int\frac{r^2}{(r^2 + d^2 -2rd\cos{\theta})^2}dr$$
where $0\leq r< \infty$, $0\leq d< \infty$ and $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$. The integral that I am getting (I used Wolfram Alpha to calculate the integral) is as follows
$$f = \frac{1}{4 \sin^2{\theta}}\left[\frac{\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{r-d\cos{\theta}}{d\sin{\theta}}\right)}}{d\sin{\theta}}+ \frac{2r\cos^2{\theta}-d\cos{\theta}-r}{r^2 +d^2 -2rd \cos{\theta}}\right]$$
which is singular at $\theta = 0,\pi$ and at $d=0$ whereas the integrand was only singular at $(r,\theta)=(d,0)$. I don't understand why is it so. Why am I getting singularities in the solution of the integral at places where there were no singularities in the integrand? Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica gives $$\frac{1}{4} \csc ^2(a) \left(\frac{2 (r \cos (2 a)-d \cos (a))}{-2 d r \cos (a)+d^2+r^2}-\frac{\csc (a) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) (d+r)}{r-d}\right)}{d}+\frac{\csc (a) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{d \sin (a)}{d \cos (a)-r}\right)}{d}\right),$$
a quick plot of which for fixed $r,d$ shows it's different to your evaluation, assuming I've not made any typos (I triple checked so should be right).

Comment: Actually, you are right that Mathematica does give the answer that you quoted. I just integrated putting $\cos{\theta}=c$ in the integral and substituting the value of $c$ into the solution after the integration.  
https://bit.ly/2BoWtYC

Answer (score 1):

The singularity of the expression signals you that the integral tends to diverge. A closer look confirms that the definite integral diverges whenever $\sin\theta=0$ and $r_1\le d\cos\theta\le r_2$, where $r_1 <r_2$ are the integration limits. You can however convince yourself that if $d\cos\theta $ is outside the integration range the definite integral converges:
$$
\lim_{\sin\theta\to0}f (r_2,d,\theta)-f (r_1,d,\theta)<\infty.
$$